# how to enable rotation only on video

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've been looking for the past days a solution to enable rotation ONLY when MPMoviePlayerViewController is triggered, without any luck.
I tried to enable the app to all rotations, and disabling it at each view, but it didn't work either.

does any one have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In target settings, enable all orientations
2. (optional, UIViewController default is portrait only) In all the other view controllers, do the following:

   ```
   // Deprecated in iOS 6, but still needed for earlier versions of iOS:
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
       return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
   }

   // For iOS 6 and up
   - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
   }
   ```
3. In the one view controller that should rotate, do the following:

   ```
   // Deprecated in iOS 6, but still needed for earlier versions of iOS:
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
       return YES;
   }

   // For iOS 6 and up
   - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
   }
   ```

This is assuming the rotating view controller will not be inside the same container view controller (such as `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController`) as the non-rotating view controllers.

Comment: I do use UINavigationController, tried to subclass it and expend the above methods, with no luck...

Comment: so, eventually I expended the UINavigationController and the UITabBarController, implemented the methods above, and it works! many thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `ViewController` for the player Full screen and add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

to your code.

Make sure you present the `ViewController`. 
(supporting iOS 6 and above)

Comment: thanks for the response, but it didn't work. does the fact that i'm using navigation controller has any relation?

Comment: Make sure all rotation are enabled in the summery of the project

Comment: but then, all the view will rotate...? I don't want the views to rotate apart from the video...